# Can anyone explain me the example of an exploit in Python’s pickle module?

Tags: python, pickle

I want to understand the the example of exploit in python pickle module?
i got a code from github which show exploit in pickle module, but still not able to understand it. please guide me.

```
import os
import pickle


class Exploit(object):
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (os.system, ('cat /etc/passwd',))


def serialize_exploit():
    shellcode = pickle.dumps(Exploit())
    return shellcode


def insecure_deserialize(exploit_code):
    pickle.loads(exploit_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    shellcode = serialize_exploit()
    insecure_deserialize(shellcode)
```

Comment: What exactly is it that you're unsure of here? The outcome or why a certain thing happens?

Comment: @Torxed am not sure why is it dangerous

Comment: The exploit is dangerous because it's an exploit. Any type of exploit is dangerous no matter what it does really. Hence my reluctance in answering your question. You basically answer your own question by asking why an exploit is dangerous ;)

Comment: @Torxed I only want explanation of above code, why is it dangerous?

Answer (score 5):

When you unpickle an object, the __reduce__ method is called. The first argument to __reduce__ is a callable, that is, a function. The next argument is a tuple of arguments for __reduce__. In this case, when Exploit is unpickled, os.system is called, and is given 'cat /etc/passwd' as the argument.

os.system allows you to make system calls according to the host operating system. In this case, it's hopefully Linux.

cat prints a file's contents to standard out, and /etc/passwd is where information on a system's users is stored. More malicious code might try and send that information over the internet, or it might try and mess with your file system, etc.

Basically, by unpickling an object you don't know anything about, you're vulnerable to whatever the __reduce__ method does.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html

Comment: `__reduce__` is called when pickling, not unpickling. It is the return value of `__reduce__` that becomes part of the the pickled data, and that data is used when unpickling. Also, using a `__reduce__` method to produce an attack is just a convenience. The vulnerability is that the pickle data format allows arbitrary callables to be specified.